# integrating facebook chat using graph api

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, chat, facebook-chat

I have been asked to integrate facebook chat in my application using javascript. I went through the chat api but that needs a domain url. I have to integrate the chat without the domain or the site url. I tried populating the online friends list through graph api, and I am able to successfully authenticate using the client flow example, but it does not redirect to my local host: http://localhost:8090/chatplugin/success.html. An error pops up telling me the resource is not found.

Is it possible to integrate FB chat using the graph api? I'm new to FB apis and I need more info.

Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Longer answer: The Graph API lets you access all the information that is stored in Facebook's social graph; the social graph is the giant web that keeps all the information on people, events, messages, etc. Chat isn't part of the graph, it's a separate application, that also uses info from the graph to populate it.

While there may be other ways to sneak around (which I don't know), the Graph api doesn't provide what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the API available on Facebook API.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/